# GKE Load Balancer Connection Refused

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set up my app on GKE and use an internal load balancer for public access. I am able to deploy the cluster / load balancer service without any issues, but when I try to access the external ip address of the load balancer, I get Connection Refused and I am not sure what is wrong / how to debug this.

These are the steps I did:

I applied my deployment `yaml` file via `kubectl apply -f file.yaml` then after, I applied my load balancer service `yaml` file with `kubectl apply -f service.yaml`. After both were deployed, I did `kubectl get service` to fetch the External IP Address from the Load Balancer.

Here is my `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app-api
          image: gcr.io/...
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "250M"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "1G"
              cpu: "500m"
        - name: my-app
          image: gcr.io/...
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "250M"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "1G"
              cpu: "500m"
```

and here is my `service.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-ilb
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: my-app-ilb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    protocol: TCP
```

My deployment file has two containers; a backend api and a frontend. What I want to happen is that I should be able to go on `[external ip address]:3000` and see my web app.

I hope this is enough information; please let me know if there is anything else I may be missing / can add.

Thank you all!

Comment: Which of the containers is your web app?

Comment: My web app is `my-app`, the one that uses the port `3000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allow traffic to flow into your cluster by creating firewall rule.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create my-rule --allow=tcp:3000
```

---

Remove this annotation :

```
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

You need external Load Balancer.

Comment: I just checked the firewall rules and it seems that GKE already created it when I created the service. I see one that is for my container, but still doesn't work..

Comment: Did GCE assign external IP address for Load Balancer ? Can you check status of load balancer? It takes time to provision Load Balancer (5-10 min). Should not your load balancer be external?

Comment: I believe GKE assigns external IP Address for Load Balancer. After deploying the `service.yaml` file and waiting around 5-10 minutes, the external ip address appeared. I pretty much followed this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing

Comment: Your tutorial says : Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing makes your cluster's services **accessible to applications** outside of your cluster **that use the same VPC network** and are located in the same GCP region. In other words this is not publicly facing load balancer, this is internal load balancer that you would use internally within VPC itself.

Comment: Ahh... I never caught that, that is probably the reason why. Will need to find a way to configure an external IP address probably. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Just re-create (or edit) service without that annotation - by default GCE will create external load balancer.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, slight mistake on my end, but learned a lot from you and from debugging this; thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Glad that could help! :)