# Connection to the Kubernetes container refused from endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I created a cluster (sample for learning) on GCP. Created a Helloworld container pulled from docker hub. I can see the container running on POD. but when I click on the endpoints, in the chrome browser it says "connection refused". I have active internet connection without any issues

any suggestions please?

[Container Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77kcg.gif)

[endpoints refused the connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwc4Q.gif)

[endpoints from cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEUY2.gif)

Comment: What about the firewall rules, did you configure the ports in the Firewall?

Comment: sorry. just started learning Kubernetes. the tutorial never spoke to about configuring ports in the firewall. can you kindly let me know how to go about that?

Comment: Daniel, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you take a look https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702818/gke-load-balancer-connection-refused ?

Comment: Thank You. I will go thru the documenation

Comment: when I use port 8080 it works.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer and add more details to your post - yaml files ?

Comment: Hello @sutterhome1976. Could you please share some more details regarding your solution?